# How to yield multiple values?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-option

I have a for comprehension like:

```
val ao = Option(1)
val bo = Option(2)
val (x,y) = for (a <- ao; b <- bo) yield (a+b, b+a*2)
```

However this does not work. For comprehension returns `Option[(Int,Int)]` but cannot be assigned to individual x and y.

If I do:

```
val Some((x,y)) = for ...
```

It causes exception when yield None.

How to achieve this goal? I want x and y to be `Option[Int]`. I hope to find an elegant solution without using like `x._1` or `x.getOrElse`, or `match`

Comment: `unzip` returns `Iterable` lists, that's sad... Hm.

Comment: Would the following help: `val (x, y) = (Option(1), Option(2)) match { case (Some(a), Some(b)) => (Some(a+b), Some(b+a*2)); case _ => (None, None) }` where `x` and `y` are `Options`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *should* have been `unzip`, but unfortunately, `unzip` returns `List`s, not `Option`s. Probably the shortest work-around would be:

```
val pairOpt = for (a <- ao; b <- bo) yield (a+b, b+a*2)
val (x, y) = (pairOpt.map(_._1), pairOpt.map(_._2))
```

Comment: Should probably submit an issue to make unzip returns the same iterable like for comprehension

Comment: @texasbruce Then you would have to persuade them first that `Option` should be `Iterable`, otherwise the types don't match. Returning implicitly converted `Option` as `Iterable` would produce a `List` anyway, because of [this](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.2/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L17).

Comment: I dig a little. Option#unzip is added by implicitly converting Option to Iterable: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.7/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L1 `option2Iterable`. Many methods under Option such as `groupBy, partition` are all added by the implicit conversion. Option has specialized methods for some methods like `map, collect` only. They might as well just inherit Iterable trait imo

Comment: NVM I see  your link just now. This is new to me. Now I need to think twice before using Option due to the conversion overhead.

Comment: PR from @texasbruce to add proper `Option#unzip` to Scala 2.13: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7360

Answer (score 0):

Isn't pattern matching the best way to handle options?

```
val res = for (a <- ao; b <- bo) yield (a+b, b+a*2)

val (x, y) = res match {
  case Some((x, y)) => (Some(x), Some(y))
  case None => (None, None)
}
```

Why would that not be considered 'elegant'?